# TF-IDF Augmented Frequency vs Cosine Normalization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, tfidf

I am using TF-IDF for text classification and have been curious about the following two concepts.

The *augmented term frequency* which is basically used for weighting in order to eliminate the bias towards longer documents.

On the other hand, there is a *cosine normalization* which appears to be done for the same purpose.

Are they both similar? Can we use any one of them to eliminate the bias towards larger documents?